# How to use "?" in regular expression to change a qualifier to be non-greedy and find a string in the middle of the data?

Tags: python, regex

I thought a qualifier would become non-greedy if I put " ? " after it. So I expected that I could get " ax: yz_bc " as the returned string by the following code:

```
import re
data = 'aaaaaax: yz_bcd'
p = re.compile('a.*?bc')

ret = p.search(data)
if ret is not None:
  print(f'{ret.group(0)}')
else:
  print('Not matched')
```

However, the string which was actually returned was " aaaaaax: yz_bc ". It was the same string which the code returned when " ? " was not added. How to explain this phenomenon? Is it because the match must start from the leftmost?

And what change should I make to my code to get " ax: yz_bc " as the returned string?

Comment: This is a common duplicate. The simplest solution by far is to say what you mean: "don't match any a:s" is `[^a]*`

Comment: The main point is to exclude the left delimiter from the `.*?` pattern, and in this case, it may be `[^a]*?`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YiAKir/2).

Comment: without `?`:  `'.*(a.*bc)'` and get `group(1)` instead of `group(0)`

Comment: to tripleee, Wiktor Stribiżew and furas: Thank you all. I think the solution " [^a]*? " is close to what I intended to do. I will adopt this solution.